# running the program with calling library

Tags: java, cmd, runtime

I have an code who called many libraries, when i try to run it in eclipse, i don't get any error like :

[image]

and the program is running perfectly. When i try to compile using cmd, i don't get any errors too like this:

[image]

And it's works. but when i try to run it with :

```
C:\ListenerZipfile\src>java -cp .;C:\ListenerZipfile\lib\commons-io-2.4.jar;C:\ListenerZipfile\lib\commons-logging.jar;C:\ListenerZipfile\lib\jnotify-0.94.jar;C:\ListenerZipfile\lib\joda-time-1.6.jar;C:\ListenerZipfile\lib\log4j-1.2.11.jar com.xxx.main.ListenerZipFile
```

it get an error like this : [image]

how to fix the command?

Comment: `javac` is just the compiler. Even if you pass the compile-time checks you can still get many runtime exceptions when you actually run the program with `java`.

Comment: yes, i know that. actually, i have done to command in cmd using javac and its works and i want to try to run it using java. But i get an error like in the picture. Can you help me to fix it?

Comment: Without any code samples and the full stack trace it would be impossible to help you debug your code.

Comment: no, when i run it in the eclipse, i don't get any error. But when i try to running in cmd. i got an error. I know that the error is in my command in cmd. it's like can not call another class in different package.

Comment: You need to post the first five or six lines of the stacktrace instead of the same four lines repeated. Without anything else to go on, this looks like an infinite loop to me, probably because your properties file couldn't be found on the classpath you provided.

Comment: i have updated my post. when try to run in eclipse, i don't get any error and when the source code try to call properties, i don't get any error. And when i try to compile in cmd using `javac`, i don't get any errors too. But, when i try to running it using `java`, i get an error, like the program cannot call the properties class.

Comment: You need to show what code is being executed on the lines referenced in the stack trace. Otherwise it's just stabbing in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

There's not much to go on, but is it possible you have a log4j configuration file (e.g. log4j.properties) that's specified using a relative path? Then, when you run the program from the command line it's no longer in the classpath so whatever utility methods you've written can't find it?